# Continuing cost of storage for hosted solution

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-storage

I've searched by can't find anything, but looking at Azure Storage and AWS S3, the rate at which you're billed is based on how much storage is used; most of these measurements are on a per month basis.

Does this mean there is a one time charge for the storage or does is compound?

EG:

*Assumption: $1/1Gb*

One month I store 30GB of data, the next month I use another 30GB of data.  Does that mean that I would pay $30 each month or would I pay $30 the first month and then $60 the next month.  The former is $60 total and the latter being $90 total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Billing is compounded based on the actual storage used.

Let's assume that on the 1st day of your billing cycle in 1st month, you upload 30 GB and then on the 1st day of your billing cycle in 2nd month, you uploaded another 30 GB.

So for 1st month you stored 30 GB thus the price would be $30 for 1st month. In the 2nd month you stored 60 GB (30 GB from 1st month and 30 GB for the 2nd month) so the price for the 2nd month would be $60. So in total you would be paying $90 in two months.

Comment: In the same vein, if you delete objects from the storage, this will reduce you monthly bill, correct?

Comment: @Justin .  Yes you pay for the space you use.  Meaning if you delete stuff then you pay less.  It is computed either daily or hourly depending on the cloud provider.  Think of it like a savings account at your bank.  They pay you a interest rate based on the daily amount of money in your account.

Comment: @MikeRobinson  Thank you for your comment.  I would have to say they are indeed doing that, but you do get some other features which would cost a lot more if you self-hosted.  EG: Backup's, configuration, etc...  or so it seems.

Comment: No question ... one has to carefully consider *all* the costs, as well as *all* the "value added."  These companies aren't being "deceitful," by any means.  (In fact, they're applying an "economy of scale" principle to all those *other* concerns, and this is indeed the core of their "value proposition.")

Comment: `In the same vein, if you delete objects from the storage, this will reduce you monthly bill, correct?` - That's correct. You pay for what you use.

Answer (score 0):

> most of these measurements are on a per month basis

Well, yes and no.  The *rate* is a monthly rate, but for object storage services, it's typical for the bill to be calculated *hourly*.

Assuming 750 (round number) hours in a month, storing 750GB for around 2 hours would be the same price as storing 2GB for the entire month.

You pay for what you use for as long as you use it, prorated against some minimum time granularity, which is typically an hour.

These questions are answered in the various vendors' documentation.

Note that this is true for object storage services, but not block storage services like Elastic Block Store.  These services give you a fixed number of GB of storage capacity in disk volumes, and you are billed for the provisioned capacity because it's all there all the time, whether you are using that space or not.